# Do group owner change if better device joins the network in wifi direct?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am creating a group using **createGroup(c,al);** method from WifiP2pManager on device A and connecting other devices to this group using **connect()** from client and **not** server(i.e one that called creategroup()). I want to know, is it the device which called creategroup() the group owner permanently (current network) or does group owner change if a better device B joins the network. If it does change will the **GroupInfoListener** of device A become inactive if in case device B becomes the new group owner. In [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#createGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)), they say

> Create a p2p group with the current device as the group owner. This essentially creates an access point that can accept connections from legacy clients as well as other p2p devices.

Do the group ownership persist ? As i am connecting client devices to device A using connect() (not calling connect method on list of client devices)

Also *is all the data routed via group owner or directly between any two device without group owner within the network*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not switch GO during ongoing connection. You have to disconnect all devices first. If you think about it is pretty clear. GO is the device that creates access point. If you would like to change GO, current GO have to turn off its access point and than after being disconnected from current GO the other device can create new access point and become GO.

As for your second question. Data is always routed through GO like so: 1st client -> group owner -> 2nd client.